# How to add string before forward slash?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to add a string before forward slash, here is a scenario:

When I have a string:
`str = "//html:div[@id='ins_storybody']/p[2]/span[1]/h2[3]/p[1]/p[4]"`

I want the expected output:
`//html:div[@id='ins_storybody']/html:p[2]/html:span[1]/html:h2[3]/html:p[1]/html:p[4]`

Here you clearly see, I am adding `html:` before forward slash.

**Note**

If there is no rectangle bracket, I don't want to add `html:`. Here is another example:

`str = "//html:div[@id='ins_storybody']/p/span[1]/h2/p[1]/p"`

Expected output:

`str = "//html:div[@id='ins_storybody']/p/html:span[1]/h2/html:p[1]/p"`

As you can see, I am not adding `html:` if there is no `[1] or []`.

I tried using this logic:

```
str = "//html:div[@id='ins_storybody']/p[2]/span[1]/h2[3]/p[1]/p[4]"
var htmlDOM = ['p', 'span', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4']

for(var i=0; i<htmlDOM.length; i++) {

    q = str.includes('[');

    if (q) {
        strSlice = str.indexOf(htmlDOM[i]);
        newstr = str.slice(0,strSlice) + 'html:' + str.slice(strSlice);
    } else {
        newstr = str;
    }

    console.log(newstr)
}
```

But looks like, this is iterating loop again and again which doesn't seems to be working perfectly.

HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED!!

Comment: What does this have to do with Java, or PHP, or Python?

Comment: I would be nicer if you start by choosing the language you want :P

Comment: Thank you I want this in javascript, python anything but mostly with Javascript as I just need the logics to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this regex pattern, which checks for `/` which is not followed by `html:` but must be followed by `any word character followed by [`

```
\/(?!html:)(?=\w*\[)
```

[image]

```js
let stringAdder = (str) => str.replace(/\/(?!html:)(?=\w*\[)/gi,"/html:")

console.log(stringAdder("//html:div[@id='ins_storybody']/p[2]/span[1]/h2[3]/p[1]/p[4]"))
console.log(stringAdder("//html:div[@id='ins_storybody']/p/span[1]/h2/p[1]/p"))
```

Comment: How did you get this flow diagram? Are you using any tool?

Comment: This is called regex visualizer, you can see one such here [`Jex.im`](https://jex.im/regulex/)